# Performance testing tool that can be automated and work on a java application deployed Google AppEngine?

Tags: performance, jmeter

I'm also battling with what performance testing tool to use for my application which would be deployed on Google AppEngine. I am familiar with Jmeter but I still can't figure out I can automate it to work on the application on Google AppEngine.

Can anybody help me out or you can recommend another Performance testing tool that can be automated and work on a java application deployed on Google AppEngine?

Answer (score 1):

- **SOASTA** (Known to work with Jenkins and other CI Frameworks) - 100 Threads non expiring license available
- **LoadRunner** (Known to work with Jenkins) - 50 virtual user non expiring license available
- **Borland/Silk Performer** (CI Integration unknown)
- **Rational Performance Tester** (CI integration unknown)

Answer (score 0):

Few more options to evaluate

- Please check http://loader.io/ (From User Suchith Parekh)
- http://blazemeter.com/
- http://grinder.sourceforge.net/